# URLError when retrieving and analyzing GOES X-Ray Sensor (XRS) data in SunPy

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve and analyze GOES X-Ray Sensor (XRS) data but getting an error. The problem was this same code used to work about 6 months ago. This is the same code I used, and the code has no changes even in the original website of SunPy (https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/generated/gallery/time_series/goes_xrs_example.html#sphx-glr-download-generated-gallery-time-series-goes-xrs-example-py) as well. Please help me out. The error is as below:

URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

INPUT:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from astropy.visualization import time_support

from sunpy import timeseries as ts
from sunpy.net import Fido
from sunpy.net import attrs as a

tstart = "2015-06-21 01:00"
tend = "2015-06-21 23:00"
result_goes15 = Fido.search(a.Time(tstart, tend), a.Instrument("XRS"), a.goes.SatelliteNumber(15))
print(result_goes15)
```

[DESIRED OUTPUT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwuir.png)